# EF Core MySQL uses inconsistent time zone when using DateTimeOffset

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-core, datetimeoffset, entity-framework-core-3.1

I'm using EF Core 3.1.1 with [MySql.EntityFrameworkCore 8.0.20](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore/). As the service is already launched, I can't update the package for the time being.

When adding a row like the following, `DateTimeOffset.Now` is evaluated *before* the SQL query is generated, i.e., the current time in the system's time zone is pushed to the database.

```cs
dbContext.Set<MyTable>().Add(new MyTable
{
    ...
    RegisteredAt = DateTimeOffset.Now
    ...
});
```

However, when retrieving rows by queries with comparisons between `DateTimeOffset` values, `DateTimeOffset.Now` is replaced with`UTC_TIMESTAMP()`, which indicates the current **UTC** time. I think this should be `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()`(or `NOW()`) as `DateTimeOffset.Now` in other contexts is considered as the current local time.

```cs
var myTable = from m in dbContext.Set<MyTable>()
              where m.RegisteredAt < DateTimeOffset.Now
              select m;
```

The generated SQL query is as follows:

```sql
SELECT ..., `i`.`RegisteredAt`, ...
FROM `Item` AS `i`
WHERE (`i`.`BeginsAt` < UTC_TIMESTAMP())
```

I found that moving `DateTimeOffset.Now` to a separate variable solves this problem, but this requires me to find and edit every LINQ queries using `DateTimeOffset.Now`.

```cs
var currentTime = DateTimeOffset.Now;
var myTable = from m in dbContext.Set<MyTable>()
              where m.RegisteredAt < currentTime
              select m;
```

Is there any feature in EF Core 3.1.1 so I can intercept the generated SQL and replace `UTC_TIMESTAMP()` to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()`?

Answer (score 1):

I found that EF Core 3 has a feature called [interceptors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/interceptors), which can be used to mutate all SQL queries before being executed. Override both `DbCommandInterceptor.ReaderExecuting` and `DbCommandInterceptor.ReaderExecutingAsync` and edit SQL queries as follows:

```cs
public override InterceptionResult<DbDataReader>, ReaderExecuting(
    DbCommand command, CommandEventData eventData, InterceptionResult<DbDataReader> result)
{
    command.CommandText = command.CommandText.Replace("UTC_TIMESTAMP()", "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()");
    return result;
}

// Do similarly in ReaderExecutingAsync
```

But I'm not sure whether this will make only limited performance impacts.